# Disabled caching for a WordPress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, plugins, shortcode

Preface: I have developed a plugin, so editing theme files is out of the question.

My shortcode function:

```
/*** [leaderboard] shortcode with tournament_id input value ***/
function leaderboard_shortcode( $tournamentid ) {
    ob_start();
    include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/leaderboard.php';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'golf-deputy-leaderboard', 'leaderboard_shortcode' );
```

I tried adding in  to relevant pages, however, if the shortcode is added to a page not controlled by the plugin - e.g. the home page - , the shortcode caches.

**I guess my question is this: what options do I have to NOT cache the content of the shortcode, even if the page it is placed on, has caching enabled.**

I have been racking my brain, the internetz, the WordPress Codex... all to no avail. I am open to any and all suggestions. Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Without disabling caching of those pages?

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: If you still want to keep the rest of the cached content cached then the only option I can think of is dynamically load the plugin content client side using javascript and insert/update it on page load

Comment: I'm not against telling WP to ignore cache for any page that has the shortcode on it...

Comment: What is your current caching setup?

Comment: That is the issue: because this is for plugin development, the caching setup can vary wildly from client to client.

Answer (score 2):

Cache functions start working before all possible filers&actions, and as shortcodes run inside the_content filter, it is impossible not to cache a shortcode only. I mean, when WP returns cached data, it returns static HTML data, no any theme&plugin's PHP runs in that case.

You need add that page (which has a shortcode in its content) to exclude list of your plugin. All popular cache plugins have such exclude field inside their settings.

Or another way is building custom cache solution which simply ignores caching then the_content contains any shortcode.